# Assigning multiple values on one line in Ruby using ||=

Tags: ruby

Now i use the following to make sure all my params values are not nil

```
start, limit = params[:start] ||= 0, params[:limit] ||= 300
sort, dir = params[:sort] ||= 'id', params[:dir] ||= 'ASC'
```

But i would like to use something like

```
params[:start], params[:limit] ||= 0, 300
params[:sort], params[:dir] ||= 'id', 'ASC'
```

but i get the error syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN, expecting '='

Has someone a better way of doing this ?

Comment: Why is it important to do it all on one line? Just because? Write code that is maintainable and readable, so that others, who write maintainable and readable code, can understand it at a glance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
params = {start: 0, limit: 300, sort: 'id', dir: 'ASC'}.merge(params)
```

Update:

The code above will work if `params` do not have specified keys, however if e.g. `params[:key]` exists and associated value is nil, nil will be the result. To fix that you can do:

```
params = {start: 0, limit: 300, sort: 'id', dir: 'ASC'}.merge(params) {|_,old,new| new || old }
```

Answer (score 1):

While writing code like:

```
start, limit = params[:start] ||= 0, params[:limit] ||= 300
sort, dir = params[:sort] ||= 'id', params[:dir] ||= 'ASC'
```

or:

```
params[:start], params[:limit] ||= 0, 300
params[:sort], params[:dir] ||= 'id', 'ASC'
```

might seem desirable because it's "tight", "concise" or "terse", it veers into the oncoming-traffic lane and becomes unreadable.

It's OK to spread out logic, because the goal is to make our code understandable to those who *might* have to maintain it at 3:00AM on Saturday night.

Instead of the above, I'd break it apart:

```
start = params[:start] ||= 0     # explain why 0
limit = params[:limit] ||= 300   # explain why 300
sort  = params[:sort]  ||= 'id'  # explain why 'id'
dir   = params[:dir]   ||= 'ASC' # explain why 'ASC'
```

or:

```
start, limit, sort, dir = params.values_at(:start, :limit, :sort, :dir)
start ||= 0     # explain why 0
limit ||= 300   # explain why 300
sort  ||= 'id'  # explain why 'id'
dir   ||= 'ASC' # explain why 'ASC'
```

In either of the above cases, I'd go one step farther to define constants to use symbolic names, rather than hard-coded "magic" values.

You *might* gain a millisecond of execution speed writing code like you want, *if* you can get it to work, but you can lose seconds or minutes of maintenance time, and irritate coworkers or others using your code because it's not normal, standard, or expected, so don't go there.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like this, which is concise and readable to me.
I need to pass the params as a whole because there might be other values there i need to build my selection.
The variable names speak for themselves and they might end up in a yaml configuration file with alle the explanation they need.

```
  def generic_data_getter (class_name, params, start=0, limit=300, sort='id', dir='ASC')
    selection = build_selection(class_name, params)
    data = class_name.where(selection).offset(start).limit(limit).order("#{sort} #{dir}")
    {:success => true, :totalCount => data.except(:offset, :limit, :order).count, :result => data.to_hash}
  end

  def get_data_for (class_name, params)
    generic_data_getter(class_name, params, params[:start], params[:limit], params[:sort], params[:dir])
  end
```